# How to prevent Rails controllers tests from finishing with errors arose in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

### manager.rb (model)

```
class Manager < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :season
  belongs_to :team

  before_validation :validate_relations

  validates :player_id, presence: true
  validates :season_id, presence: true
  validates :team_id, presence: true

  private

  def validate_relations
    player = Player.find(self.player_id)
    season = Season.find(self.season_id)
    team = Team.find(self.team_id)

    manager = Manager.find_by(player: player, season: season, team: team)

    if !manager.nil? && self.id != manager.id
      errors[:manager] << 'already exists.'
      false
    end
  end
end
```

### managers_controller.rb (controller)

```
class ManagersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_manager, only: [:destroy, :show, :update]
  rescue_from ActionController::ParameterMissing, with: :malformed_request
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :record_not_found

  def create
    @manager = Manager.create(manager_params)
    status = @manager.valid? ? :no_content : :unprocessable_entity

    render_manager status
  end

  ...

  private

  def manager_params
    params.require(:manager).permit(:player_id, :season_id, :team_id, :league_id)
  end

  def malformed_request
    render_manager :unprocessable_entity, 'Error message'
  end

  def record_not_found
    render_manager :not_found, 'Error message'
  end

  def get_manager
    @manager = Manager.includes(:player, :season, :team).find(params[:id])
  end

  def render_manager(status, message = nil)
    ...
  end

  def render_managers(status, managers)
    ...
  end
end
```

As you see, my `managers_controller` rescues from `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` and takes care of responses accordingly when the client tries to create invalid associates ids. This works great when the request and the response were explicitly given but when I do `rake test`, the test with the invalid associates ids (for example when all the ids are `nil`) always ends with 3 errors stating that rails couldn't find each Model with the given id as below.

```
  1) Error:
ManagerTest#test_: Manager should require player_id to be set. :
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Player with 'id'=
    app/models/manager.rb:35:in `validate_relations'


  2) Error:
ManagerTest#test_: Manager should require season_id to be set. :
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Player with 'id'=
    app/models/manager.rb:35:in `validate_relations'


  3) Error:
ManagerTest#test_: Manager should require team_id to be set. :
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Player with 'id'=
    app/models/manager.rb:35:in `validate_relations'
```

How can I re-design the test, or model validation, or error handling to avoid these errors?

Comment: I would redesign the tests in a way that they explicitly expect to raise that error when you test for invalid ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your `Manager` model needs a validation that will check if current model is unique based on `Team`, `Season`, and `Player` models. There's a built-in validator for that, called [`uniqueness`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) ([detailed docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of)), you just need:

```
class Manager < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :season
  belongs_to :team

  validates :player_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:team_id, :season_id] }
end
```

You can also use [shoulda-matchers](http://matchers.shoulda.io/docs/v3.0.0/Shoulda/Matchers/ActiveRecord.html#validate_uniqueness_of-instance_method) for testing.

Answer (score 0):

In general for unit testing you want to test one class independent of another class, so in your case you want to test the controller independent of the model, so you should provide a "mock" of the model.

I am not sure what testing framework you are using but here is an [example](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-4/docs/mocks/mock-model) from the rspec documentation:

You use [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails) to create sample model data.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from testing methodology, I find it quite odd that a validation throws a not_found... Why don't you just rescue (or use `Player.find_by(:id => self.player_id)`, which would return `nil`) in your validation, so you could return messages like:

```
{
 :errors => [
   { "Player" => "not found" },
   { "Season" => "not valid" },   
   { "Team" => "not whatever" }
 ]
}
```